# "Match a literal character", or "match a character literally"?

Tags: regex

I was making a RegEx using the [regex101 tool](http://regex101.com/) and read in the explanation field

`[.]` - the literal character `.`

`[\.]` - matches the character `.` literally

I get lost between "literal character" and "character literally".
What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Sorry, I take that back. The only difference the words that Firas Dib, the author of regx101, chose to explain various tokens.

A `literal` character or matching something `literally` refers to specifying an actual character in the text: for instance, `a` to match `a`, as opposed to a character class such as `\w` that could also match `a`.

You can match a literal period in either of these three ways:

1. `\.`
2. `[.]`
3. `[\.]`

**Which Option is Better?**

- Some people like option 2 because it makes it clear you are matching a period, not the catch-all dot. It stands out. For myself, I use `\.`. Some people will say that using a character class is less optimal, but on modern processors it makes no difference. You pick.
- Option 3 is over the top and is typically used when someone doesn't know that periods don't need to be escaped inside a character class. In my view it's confusing. What did the author mean? Were they trying to create a character class to match either a backslash or a period, and made a typo? (That would be `[\\.]`

Comment: FYI beefed up the explanation :)

Comment: Thank you! was confused first with different answers pointing on different directions... but yours seems to be the only survivor and does makes sense.